# What is the list view in Windows Explorer called?

Tags: windows-os, names

In Windows Explorer, the Details view looks like this:

[image: Windows Explorer details view]

As you can see, there is a list view in which the items can be sorted by one of many attributes.  I would like to know what this sort of list view is called.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't think your question is UX related but check out this MS doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511485.aspx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows, it's known as a [List View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511485.aspx). Although you would not be chastised for simply calling it a "sortable table".

Mac OSX has the same sort of control, which is called out as a "list view or table" inside of the OSX HIG.

[image]

Java also has the same control type, but they call it a "TableView". OpenJDK even has some user experience docs on it: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/TableView+User+Experience+Documentation.

[image]

Note that while the above is not a file list, the ability of Java to alter a controls look-and-feel would easily produce a file list from a TableView. Java does actually have a "ListView" control too, which could also be made to behave as Windows and Mac's (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/ListView+User+Experience+Documentation)